# How do I change the dpi in Properties of a jpeg from 96 to 300?

Tags: dpi

I need to change the dpi shown *in the Properties* of a printscreen jpeg image from 96 dpi to 300 dpi for text editing in Abbyy. How do I do this in Microsoft Paint or other freeware? I need to change the dpi shown in Properties, not just change the image size.

Comment: Why is this -1?

Comment: My guess is that it's because your question is not very clear and you didn't include any attempts or research that you tried

Answer (score 5):

Almost any decent program can do this. But depending on which one you are using you need to "block" the file size.

I understand that Abbyy you are refering to is the OCR program. And somehow is a little "dumb" needing the file to declare that it is on 300 dpi.

If you are using windows try irfanview www.irfanview.com
Then go to Image > Resize/Resample and do not touch anithing but the box where you define the ppi (actually it says DPI)

On any plataform use gimp www.gimp.org

Image > Scale Image and change the X and Y resolution. Simply do not touch the pixel values.

This two cases will simply change the little data embeded in the file.

- Neither of this will modify the image itself. but if you try to print it yes you totally are saying to the printer that the file will be much smaller, but only when printing. That ppi value is just an instruction for the printer.

Answer (score 1):

I voted it down, because this question is basically just asking for us to tell you how to do something (a tutorial) and that's not what this site is built around.  It's also something that can be found easily with a Google search.

That being said, here's your solution:

[Download Adobe CC](http://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/start-with-free-creativecloud.html) and take advantage of their free trial

Open the image in Photoshop and go to Image > Image Size

[image: settings]

If you wish *not* to change the image's size, uncheck Resample

Change the resolution to whatever you want.

Comment: I tried a few tutorials but none of them changed the dpi in Properties, they just made my image bigger which didn't matter to Abbyy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please don't berate someone for not searching heard enough and then give them the answer anyway, you're undermining your own point and encouraging others to ask lazy questions. That said, the OP asked specifically for _freeware_, which Photoshop is not, even in the trial. There are literally directness of free tools that can do this.

Comment: @PieBie I wouldn't call what I did berating, I was just explaining to the OP why the question was -1.  I wasn't even planning to answer and actually had my first paragraph typed as a comment, but I have a lot of time on my hands today and it's a very simple answer, so I figured "Why not?"  I just checked now and Adobe CC is still offering free trials, so for 30 days it's free.  Not "freeware" per se, but still free for a bit.

Comment: Umph, autocorrect seems to have had its way with my last comment, sorry about that. You give the OP _two_ distinct reasons of why their question is not good for this site. I'm not going to argue semantics with you, since I'm not a native speaker, but I think your point remains the same. By then giving them the easy answer anyway you're just encouraging them and others to keep posting lazy questions. But I don't want to start a comment war, so I'll leave it at that. You can always come find me in chat if you want to take this up further.

Answer (score 1):

Try using https://convert.town/image-dpi, which is freeware mentioned in these related [Super User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693348/setting-jpg-density-dpi-with-no-increase-in-file-size) and [Stack Overflow](https://superuser.com/questions/607663/how-to-change-the-dpi-of-an-image/917238) questions:

> You can change the DPI of your jpeg image without an application using
>   this free online tool:
>
> https://convert.town/image-dpi
>
> 1. Enter your new DPI value
> 2. Upload your image.
> 3. Download the adjusted
>      image.

Comment: Thank you so much. I created an account here just to up vote your answer.